# Local $\mathbb{k}$-algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(A,m)$ and $(B,n)$ be local commutative rings that are also $\mathbb{k}$-algebras. Let $\phi :B \rightarrow A$ be a local $\mathbb{k}$-algebra homomorphism.

Suppose that $A/m \cong \mathbb{k}$. I want to show that $B/n \cong \mathbb{k}$.

If we call the maps

$\tau : \mathbb{k} \rightarrow B \twoheadrightarrow B/n$

$\overline{\phi}: B/n \rightarrow A/m$,

$\rho : \mathbb{k} \rightarrow A \twoheadrightarrow A/m$

I have shown that $\overline{\phi}\circ\tau = \rho$. $\textbf{If we suppose further that $\rho$ is an isomorphism}$, as $\overline{\phi}$ is injective, it follows that $\tau$ must be surjective and hence an isomorphism (as it is already a nonzero ring homomorphism from a field).

But I don't see why $\rho$ has to be an isomorphism?

I don't think that the fact $A/m \cong \mathbb{k}$ implies that $\rho$ is an isomorphism, as the inclusion $k(t^2) \hookrightarrow k(t)$ gives a counterexample (see [Local $k$-algebra with residue field $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515093/local-k-algebra-with-residue-field-k)). So I am not sure that my approach is even on the right track!

This problem is related to Hartshorne Chapter 2, exercise 2.15.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668789/is-hartshorne-exercise-ii-2-15b-correct-as-written/3668801#3668801) is some discussion about what's going on in Hartshorne exercise II.2.15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want $A/m\cong k$ **as a $k$-algebra** then that is saying that $\rho$
is an isomorphism, at least in my book.

But one can have $A/m\cong k$ **just as a ring isomorphism** and then $B/n$
need not be isomorphic to $k$. As an example, take a tower of field
extension $k\subset L\subset K$ with $k\cong K$ and $k\not\cong L$. Then let
$(A,m)=(K,0)$ and $(B,n)=(L,0)$.

Why do such fields exist? For example, take $k=\Bbb C$, $L=\Bbb C(t)$ and $K$
the algebraic closure of $L$.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the clarification.